# Перевести sql запрос в LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Есть часть запроса SQL

```
24 * SUM(ISNULL(CAST(time_op AS float), 0)) AS t_regl
```

,где time_op имеет тип DateTime. Мне нужно эту строчку реализовать с помощью linq

Я делала так:

```
Sum  = 24 * gg.Sum(z =>z.time_op == null ? "01.01.1900 0:00:00" : z.time_op)
```

естественно это не работает и куча ошибок с преобразованиями.
Помогите sql переделать в linq

Comment: Что такое `gg` и `z`?

Comment: var left = (from l in _db.UMRK_OP
                        where l.Regl == false && l.Operation == "Итого"
                        group l by new { l.Id_rem } into gg
                        
                        select new
                        {
                            Id_rem = gg.Key.Id_rem,
                            Sum  = 24 * gg.Sum(z =>z.time_op == null ? "01.01.1900 0:00:00" :  z.time_op),
                         
                        });
Это весь код моего горе запроса

Comment: Не пишите код в комментариях. Нажмите ссылку [edit] и отредактируйте вопрос, переместив код в него. И приведите определение сущности (entity). Иначе вам вряд ли помогут.